# PHP current url issue

Tags: php, url

I'm trying to get current page url. Here is the code:

```
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

It works fine. But I'm dealing with problem:

```
<a title="LT" href="<?php echo $url; ?>?lang=lt">LT</a>
```

When I press "LT" link once again, it gives me result:

```
http://127.0.0.1/index.php?lang=lt?lang=lt
```

How to avoid this?

Comment: do you realise you have pass the variable $_Server['SERVER_NAME']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns everything after the domain including the querystring (Well... not everything, since it can't return fragments...)

If you want to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` then you could explode it like so:

```
$uri = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$uri = $uri[0];
```

And then use the `$uri` variable in place of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` like this:

```
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$uri : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$uri;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this code very helpful

```
$protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') === 
FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';            // Get protocol HTTP/HTTPS
$host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];   // Get  www.domain.com
$script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; // Get folder/file.php
$params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];// Get Parameters occupation=odesk&name=ashik

$currentUrl = $protocol . '://' . $host . $script . '?' . $params; // Adding all

echo $currentUrl;
```